# Duplicate key exception reading map from edn file

Tags: clojure

I am persisting a Clojure map to a file using

```
(spit (str tmpdir "/" "results.edn") (.toString c))
```

where `c` is a very large hash-map (the file is 201MB). The keys of the map are strings and the values are numbers.

When I try to read the map back in from the file I'm getting a duplicate key exception. Here is how I'm trying to read it back in

```
(def phrases (edn/read 
                (PushbackReader. 
                  (io/reader
                    "/tmp/mednotes8910030368496690883/results.edn"))))
```

How can the map end up with duplicate keys when it is written out to the edn file? Any ideas?

Here's the meat of the exception:

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
   Duplicate key: ? 5

    PersistentHashMap.java:   67  clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap/createWithCheck
                   RT.java: 1538  clojure.lang.RT/map
            EdnReader.java:  631  clojure.lang.EdnReader$MapReader/invoke
            EdnReader.java:  142  clojure.lang.EdnReader/read
            EdnReader.java:  108  clojure.lang.EdnReader/read
                   edn.clj:   35  clojure.edn/read
                   edn.clj:   33  clojure.edn/read
                  AFn.java:  154  clojure.lang.AFn/applyToHelper
                  AFn.java:  144  clojure.lang.AFn/applyTo
```

As requested, here is a sample of what is in the map:

```
{"cervical region of" 32,
 "partial brachial" 64,
 "is an effective medication for" 32,
 ", as stopping them" 32,
 ", supportive treatment" 160,
 "should be eating a normal" 128,
 "o call back if supplement" 32,
 "diagnosiscod diabc }" 32,
 "days in case of allergies" 32,
 "ointment 8 drops" 32,
 "leg from pinched" 32,
...
```

@fl00r suggested in the comments to grep the results.edn file for the string "? 5". Using egrep to show the 20 characters before and after this string, I get 4 entries with that key:

```
[/tmp/mednotes8910030368496690883]> egrep -o ".{20}\"\? 5\" .{20}" results.edn 
oothbrush for" 160, "? 5" 32, ". ) during his 
t with sutures" 32, "? 5" 352, "4.81 pounds" 1
"being up all" 32, "? 5" 32, "limited financi
everytime she" 32, "? 5" 32, "had a partial m
```

interesting that 3 of the 4 have exactly the same counts. Still not sure how this can happen when written from a seemingly good map that doesn't have these duplications.

Comment: some of your input (the contents of c) would help a lot

Comment: You should use `(pr-str)` to print objects which ensures that it can be read by the reader.

Comment: @Andre I think .toString is a call to pr-str, anyone know otherwise? in general it's better to use the pr* functions, though I can't find an example where .toString on a map returns something not = to what pr-str returns

Comment: either his data is corrupt, (left over from a partial write in a previous run) or my assumption is incorrect?

Comment: Try to grep your file `grep /tmp/mednotes8910030368496690883/results.edn "? 5"`

Comment: Not sure that grep will be very helpful. The file consists of a single line. The fact remains that a perfectly find map is somehow being written out to the file with at least one duplicate key. Tells me that I must be writing the map out to the file wrong. Unfortunately the process takes about 4 hours to run so it's quite a lengthy try/fail process. It works fine on the smaller data sets of 2-3 files I've been testing on. Just seems to fail when I try to process all 235 files.

Comment: @fl00r After thinking about your suggestion some more I at least figured out how to get something from grep. Sure enough it looks like there are 4 entries in the file with the key "? 5". Still not sure how that happens though.

Comment: So now you have got brand new problem :)

Comment: It is clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap

Comment: It is impossible to have duplicated keys in map, so the problems is somewhere else. Maybe you append to this file, or you modify it somewhere else

Comment: Possible encoding problem? Does the key `"? 5`" actually map to something in the original data? Second Q: Does `tmpdir` stay the same among runs? You have the tmp dir hard coded in the `io/reader` call.

Comment: Yes, the key "? 5" does exist in the map. tmpdir changes each run. The io/reader call was one example of a read from the repl, so I change it each time to the last written file.

Comment: 1. try to find out if other keys are duplicated 2. are all values for key `? 5` the same in your tmp file? 3. Are there other keys which include `5`? what are they?